# Containerization of SDL DXA 2.2 .Net application

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, dxa-net, docker

We are running SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 and DXD services version 11.1.0-1054.

We are planning to containerize DXA for our environment.

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange question and answer site. It's not clear to me exactly what your question is. It helps people to write good answers if the question is clear. Have you already tried containerising DXA and had problems? What worked? What didn't work? What's your question?

Comment: DXA .NET or Java?

Comment: In the question, it's mentioned DXA 2.2 .Net application

Comment: Ah, I see now. Updated the tags accordingly.

Comment: @DominicCronin We Didn't containerize it yet. But we are looking for the documentation for containerizing DXA .net 2.2 and WebApps

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible. See, for example, https://blog.alexellis.io/run-iis-asp-net-on-windows-10-with-docker/

Answer (score 0):

As of now DXA .NET 2.2 still not yet supported in .NET core and run-in containerize.

[Are there plans for DXA .NET on ASP.NET Core?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16590/are-there-plans-for-dxa-net-on-asp-net-core)

Comment: Note that OP didn’t mention .NET or Java. Plus you can also run IIS + ASP.NET in a Windows Docker Container nowadays. See https://blog.alexellis.io/run-iis-asp-net-on-windows-10-with-docker/